# Partial differential equation with conditions

Tags: differential-equations, syntax, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve this PDE with Mathematica, and I have checked the syntax a lot, but still don't get a solution

```
Equa = (-4*f[r, \[Theta]]^3 - 3*Derivative[0, 1][f][r, \[Theta]]^2 + 2*f[r, \[Theta]]*(Cot[\[Theta]]*Derivative[0, 1][f][r, \[Theta]] + 
        Derivative[0, 2][f][r, \[Theta]]) + 4*f[r, \[Theta]]^2*(1 + (a - r)*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, \[Theta]]))/
     (4*(a - r)^2*f[r, \[Theta]]^2) == -(r - a*Cos[\[Theta]]) + B; 

DSolve[{Equa, f[r, Pi/2] == 1 + r^3/4 - r^2*(B/3), f[r, 3*(Pi/2)] == 1 + r^3/4 - r^2*(B/3), f[0, Pi/2] == 1}, 
  f[r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta]}]
```

Comment: Very likely, Mathematica simply can't find the analytic solution. However, in order for other people to check that, please edit you question and copy&paste the code from Mathematica (instead of a screenshot).

Comment: You haven't copied the code properly. (You should not copy it as plain text. ) See this post for more info: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/1871

Comment: hopefully now its good

Comment: Your IC do not make much sense to me. You have `f[r, Pi/2] == ....` and also `f[0, Pi/2]=...` Mathematica will not like `f[0, Pi/2]=` because it is not on single edge of the domain.

Comment: it does not work even without f[0, Pi/2]=...

Comment: Try numerical solver `NDSolve`. There is very little chance this can be solved analytically.

Comment: I've tried NDSolver too, it is also disappointing

Comment: I am reasonably confident that `DSolve` cannot obtain a symbolic solution to `Equa`, because none exists.  I recommend that you try again to solve it numerically with `NDSolve`.  If unsuccessful, post a new question that describes clearly the problems you encountered with `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried NDSolver too, it is also disappointing

Here is numerical solution. The trick is to give domain starting and ending where the boundary conditions for $\theta$ are given.  I made some numerical values for your $a,B$. The other important thing to do is to move the denominator of the ode to the RHS!  Without this `NDSolve` was not happy. (what a picky function NDSolve is :)

i.e. instead of

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Write the pde as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
B = 1;
a = 2;
pde = (-4*f[r, θ]^3 - 3*D[f[r, θ], r]^2 + 2*f[r, θ]*(Cot[θ]*D[f[r, θ], x] + 
       D[f[r, θ], θ]) + 4*f[r, θ]^2*(1 + (a - r)*D[f[r, θ], r])) == (-(r - 
        a*Cos[θ]) + B)*(4*(a - r)^2*f[r, θ]^2)
```

Now set up the boundary conditions

```
icTheta = {f[r, Pi/2] == 1 + r^3/4 - r^2*(B/3), f[r, 3*(Pi/2)] == 1 + r^3/4 - r^2*(B/3)}
icR = {f[0, θ] == 1}
```

And now

```
NDSolve[{pde, icTheta, icR}, f, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, Pi/2, 3*Pi/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There were numerical warnings message about `accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller  grid spacing can be specified`  and so on,. You can now play with NDSolve option to try to eliminate these messages.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know that NDSolve is so picky, it was very helpful